# What is wrong that Bind Param is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am executing a Stored Procedure on another server. I want to be able to pass my paramaters/variables to that Stored Procedure. However, my code stops short of that as it fails on the bindParam part.

I have looked at bindParam online and at different examples. I have tried may different things and variations but nothing seems to work. I assume it must be a syntax error someplace but code checks out in editor.

```php
try {


    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$database", $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    if($conn){

    echo "Connection is good.... <br />";
    $sql = 'CALL web.WebImportWoRequestDirect (:WebREQUESTEDBY, :WebSTARTDATE, :WebFINISHDATE, :WebTASKDESC, :WebSITEID, :WebLOCATION, :WebPRIORITY, :WebESTDURATION, :WebPHONE, :WebEXT, :WebTEXTS)';

    echo "Stored Procedure has been called....<br />";

    // prepare for execution of the stored procedure
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    echo "Preparing SQL Statement... <br />";

    // pass value to the command
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebREQUESTEDBY', 'WEBUSER00001', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebSTARTDATE', '06-28-2019', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebFINISHDATE',  '06-29-2019', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebTASKDESC',  'Title Here...', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebSITEID',  'UMONCTON', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebLOCATION',  'Some Place', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebPRIORITY',  '2', PDO::PARAM_NUM);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebESTDURATION',  '', PDO::PARAM_NUM);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebPHONE',  '555-555-5555', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebEXT', 'MCH1', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':WebTEXTS',  'Massive text here...', PDO::PARAM_LOB);

    echo "CHECK - pass value to the command...<br />";

    //Execute the stored procedure...
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Executed Stored Procedure....<br />";

    #$conn = null;
    }
    echo "Well... ask Gif if it worked...";

} catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "There is some problem in connection: <br />" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

What I want is to be able to pass the variables to the stored procedure...

Comment: It would be helpful if you let us know the error you're getting.

Comment: Not getting an error... If I was I could try an figure it out. The script just stops at Preparing SQl Statement... no error.

Comment: You need to start logging errors and checking what the error log file tells you.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

The method [bindParam](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) requires a **variable** as the second parameter. You are using strings.

If you don't want to use variable you should use the [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) method instead.

So it's either:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':WebREQUESTEDBY', 'WEBUSER00001', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

or

```
$webuser = 'WEBUSER00001';
$stmt->bindParam(':WebREQUESTEDBY', $webuser, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**Problem 2**

`PDO::PARAM_NUM` is not a valid constant. Use `PDO::PARAM_INT` instead.

Comment: I have tried with and without those data types and I am getting the same result. The script stops at "Preparing SQL statement" I have changed them around as well setting those number fields to strings and such. but the script always stops at the same place.

Comment: I just tried both ways. using bindParam and bindValue. Each time the script ends in the same place. I even tried bindvalue with using the variable instead of hard coding it with a string. I also tried just sending webRequestedby alone and still nothing. I have even tried removing the whole PDO::PARAM_STR part and still no dice... the only thing I can think of is that the ':WebREQUESTEDBY' must be wrong...

Comment: Edited again, `PDO::PARAM_NUM` is not a valid constant. Use `PDO::PARAM_INT` instead. You need to fix both problems in my answer. Also, you might want to catch all throwable errors instead of only PDOExceptions.

Comment: Hey Bram, I just added an echo after each BindParam to see if I was getting past it... just found out that the PARAM_NUM was holding it up... fixing that now... however, I have a syntax error now.... and it is vague... SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Can't really help you there. Maybe update the code in your question with your current version?